# Shopping Cart using Session ( Local Storage ) in php

Tags: php, arrays, session, html-table, shopping-cart

I'm trying to create a simple shopping cart.

**Main problem**
The page `insertCart.php` always add one product on view cart and does not add another.

**Secondary issues:**

- How to show an image of a product on the view cart
- how to add multiple items on the cart using session
- how to calculate the total amount of products increased.

Using a session I have tried to get the data from product details page and when user click on the button add to cart, product item will be added.

**This is the code I used so far**

```
insertCart.php
<?php
    //start session
    session_start();
    include('connection/db.php');
    //get the values
    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $price    = $_POST['price'];
    $quantity = $_POST['qty'];
    $image    = $_POST['image'];
    //storing values in an array and assign it to a variable
    $product  = array($name, $price, $quantity,$image);
    //store arrays values in session varialbe '$name'
    $_SESSION['$name'] = $product;
    header('location: view_cart.php');
?>
```

Comment: You are storing a single item into a brand new array each time. You are not appending the current item to an existing array.

Comment: please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `'$name'` in single quotes, which mean "don't interpret special characters in this string, and especially don't insert any variables, even if I use the `$` symbol". So the result is the same every time it's run.

To expand the variable into the string, you need double quotes:

```
$_SESSION["$name"] = $product;
```

But since you're just using the name on its own, in this case you don't need quotes at all:

```
$_SESSION[$name] = $product;
```